# All the product topologies

Tags: general-topology, product-space, box-topology

I wonder what are all the topologies on the product of spaces that satisfy certain properties. For example, let $(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of topological spaces and let $X:=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ be the Cartesian product of these sets. Also, let $\pi_i:X\rightarrow X_i,i\in I$ be the canonical projections. Now, the Tychonoff's topology on the set $X$ satisfies these two properties:

1. For all $i\in I$, the mapping $\pi_i$ is continuous.
2. For all $i\in I$, the mapping $\pi_i$ is open.

It is easy to prove that [Tychonoff's topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) is the coarsest topology on the set $X$ that satisfies these two properties. The [box topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) is another topology on the set $X$ that satisfies these two properties. I want to know if the box topology is, as the opposite, the finest topology on the set $X$ that satisfies these two properties. I also want to know (if my previous assumption is false) what is some characterization of all the topologies on the set $X$, beside these two, that satisfy these two properties.

Comment: The finest topology on any set is the discrete topology and in general the box topology won't be the discrete topology.

Comment: @0XLR The discrete topology doesn't satisfy two properties that I wrote up there. So, I already excluded it.

Comment: @0XLR Projections from the discrete topology are always continuous, but are they always open?

Comment: [This list of papers involving box products](http://www.math.buffalo.edu/~sww/0papers/BoxProductsReferences.pdf) might be of interest. There are also things called $\Sigma$-products and $\sigma$-products, and the google search [product + Corson + topology](https://www.google.com/search?q=product+Corson+topology) will get you started.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you! I will check that out soon.

Comment: Note, though, that sigma products are subspaces of the Cartesian product with its usual topology, not a different topology on the product.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Just to be clear, this was not an oversight on my part -- I don't know the first thing about $\Sigma$-products or $\sigma$-products (and obviously I didn't try to learn either)! I figured something like this would be in one of the articles in a book I got 2 or 3 months ago ([**Encyclopedia of General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0444503552)), in particular *b-3. Product Spaces* (pp. 37-42) where I saw $\Sigma$-products and $\sigma$-products as the title of the 3rd section, and went from there (without looking at what they mean).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take the box product on $\Bbb R^\omega$ for example, in which the "diagonal"
$D = e[\Bbb R]$ is not open (where $e: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^\omega$ maps $x$ to the constant sequence with value $x$.) we can add $D$ to the box topology and generate a strictly larger topology that still obeys 1 and 2. (1 because it's finer than the product topology and 2 because $\pi_n[D]=\Bbb R$ is not going to "spoil" the opennness.). So I think the answer to your question is "no" in general (it's trivially true for a product of discrete spaces, as the box topology is then also discrete).

Comment: Your answer indeed made my understanding of topologies on product much clearer. Thank you very much!

Comment: We can also conclude that, in general case, there is no the maximal topology that satisfy my two properties. Take for example $I=\{1,2\}$, $X_1=X_2=\mathbb{R}$, $D_1=\{(x,x)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $D_2=\{(x,-x)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Now, if you extend the box topology on $X_1\times X_2$ with either $D_1$ or $D_2$, you get a valid topology. But if you extend it with both $D_1$ and $D_2$, you don't. Because $\{(0,0)\}$ would be open and its projections wouldn't. So we cannot characterize all such topologies as all topologies between Tychonoff's and some else.